# How to measure distance between camera and an object?

Tags: python, opencv

I'm an OpenCV beginner, just wondering which way would be the best to measure
the distance between the camera to an object in a given video.

Every tutorial I encountered before tutor by using camera calibration first and then undistorting the camera lens. But in this case I don't use my own camera, so is it necessary for me to use these functions?

In addition, I some data of the recording camera, such as:

- (fx,fy) = focal length
- (cx,cy) = principle point
- (width,height) = image shape
- radial = radial distortion
- (t1,t2) = tangential distortion.

Comment: Do you know the dimension of the object ? If you can link a metric measurement on the image plane to an apparent pixel measurement yes you can figure out the distance from that object to the camera.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, but that doesn't answer my question. Do I have to use camera calibration and/or undistortion?

Comment: you will have to take a class on computer vision or read chapters of a suitable book. http://szeliski.org/Book/ is free

Comment: @WhiteDragon without lens distortion correction you will get errors whenever you rely on pixel measurements (size/position of the pixels). If that's a problem depends on the accuracy you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, one does measure the distance between a single camera and an object with prior knowledge of the object. It could be the dimensions of a planar pattern or the 3D positions of edges that can easily be detected automatically using image analysis.

The computation of the position of the object with respect to the camera is usually done by solving a PnP problem.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perspective-n-Point

Solving the PnP equations do require the camera parameters (at least the intrinsic matrix, and ideally the distortion coefficients for more accuracy).

These parameters can be estimated by calibrating your camera. OpenCV provides a handful of functions that you can use to calibrate your monocular camera. Alternatively, you can use a platform like [CalibPro](https://calibpro.com) to compute these parameters for you.

[Disclaimer] I am the founder of Calibpro. I am happy to help you use the platform and I'd love your feedbacks on your experience using it.